# "Browser Not Supported" Error When Web Scraping With BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape a website but I keep getting this "Browser not supported" error. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

```
import bs4
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.get("https://revengeofficial.com/webstore", headers=headers)

page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(session.text, "html.parser")

print(page.title.text)
```

Output: http://prntscr.com/kozv1x

Edit: After multiple attempts I still cannot find a solution, can anyone else help?

Comment: Likely the site operates on Javascript and doesn't output any useful HTML directly. You'll need a headless browser that can evaluate that Javascript…

Comment: The thing is, it used to work fine like two weeks ago and now this is happening. So I doubt that’s the issue.

Comment: Test the site with Firefox and use the User-Agent Switcher plugin, set your user agent above and check what happen. IMHO the site's javascript/server side checks your user agent and simply answer this if it is not among those few that it supports.

Comment: I tried multiple different user agents using the switcher plugin and they all seem to work. When I try adding the user agent string to my program I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The following user agent appears to work:

```
import bs4
import requests

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405'}
session = requests.get("https://revengeofficial.com/webstore", headers=headers)
page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(session.text, "html.parser")

print(page.title.text)
```

This displayed:

```
WEBSHOP — Revenge — Official Clothing Shop
```

If this does not work for you, try and use a different IP address to make your request. It could also be possible that you have made too many requests to the server.

Tested using Python 3.6.3, Requests 2.18.4, BeautifulSoup 4.6.0

Comment: I am still getting the same output - http://prntscr.com/kp04fn

If it was a request overflow it shouldn't work on regular google chrome either, but it does load.

Comment: Maybe you are under a proxy? Are you able to access to other sites with python?

Comment: Yes, I am able to access other sites such as google.com, nfl.com, etc. I am not under a proxy and I tried at two different households as well as using VPNs and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Which versions of `Requests` and `BeautifulSoup` are you using?  Perhaps updating them might help. e.g. `print(bs4.__version__)`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related with the user-agent header.
I tried doing a GET request in POSTMAN with your user-agent and it did not work, but with this one it did:

'User-Agent' ; 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'

Comment: I'm getting the exact same "browser not supported" error when using the agent you just provided. Also you had a typo in the word "Agent" but I fixed that and still get the same error.